# How to use the rollback pattern with NHibernate transactions? 

Tags: c#, nhibernate, testing, transactions

I'd like to use [the rollback pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/autp5.aspx#The%20Rollback%20Pattern12) for testing my services. These are actually logical services that manage transactions and handle all repository access, called by a Winform UI. The repositories use NHibernate for database operations.

Given [NHibernate doesn't support nested transactions](http://blog.constructionhive.com/2010/07/22/nested-transactions-and-nhibernate/), it doesn't work to begin a transaction in test setup and rollback in tear down. My transactions executed in-between were not rolled back.

The only way I've found is changing the service class so that I can inject to it the `ITransaction` created in test setup. But this method exposes the transaction to the UI as a side-effect and feels like changing my implementation just for testing.

Is there a better way to achieve this? Any suggestions or directions are welcome.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding properly, but is there a particular problem with simply using the in-memory database that NHibernate provides for your testing?  You needn't worry about rolling back tests when your database will expire at the end of the test script anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is more of an integration test where I'd like to test against a Sybase Anywhere database, which has some quirks. In unit tests I go for the in-memory database.

Comment: Oh, gotcha.  I did something like this at my last job - it may not be appropriate for your situation but it's at least something.  A moment while I type it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same problem at one of my previous jobs, and honestly the situation was so thorny we ended up ducking the problem by having a test database.

The basic idea is that you have some base-line snapshots or base setup script for your database, which you run on your test server daily, hourly, or whenever the tests run - whatever's appropriate.  The way we handled it was to have the SetUp method to reset to baselines by invoking a script; we would then do all our tests, and reset to baselines a second time during the TearDown procedure (if we needed).

You can even set up the baseline location as a parameter so you can pull in baselines from QA for changes that shouldn't break anything, and local baselines if you're testing changes.  All in all, it was a little awkward to get used to, but it worked well and did not bog down our development process.